# What is the meaning of found one's claim to something?

Tags: idioms

I can not get what it means to "found one's claim to something".

For example:

> Television’s ‘peculiar form of presentness’ **founds its triumphal
>   claims to** immediacy

Source: Communication Theory; Media, Technology and Society belonging to David Holmes

Answer (score 1):

To *find one's claim to X* means for one to achieve something that would make others say that one is X.

> She finally found her claim to fame in her acting abilities

"Claim to fame" is the first thing that comes to my mind with this.

So:

> Television’s ‘peculiar form of presentness’ finds its triumphal claims to immediacy

It is saying that a 'peculiar form of presentness' is something that television has achieved, and that, as a result, television has a "claim to immediacy."  So television's 'peculiar form of presentness' is something that makes others/everyone say "this is immediate."

Compared to former media delivery methods, such as newspapers and books (interesting that it doesn't consider radio, though), television makes people wait less for information - therefore making people turn to television to know what is happening right now - and that's probably what the sentence is trying to say.

---

If your original sentence is really "*founds* its triumphal claims to immediacy" - *to found* (past tense *founded*) means to start an institution or foundation, or to create the root of a great change lasting generations.  I don't hear *found to claim* very often but it may be an intentional play on words.

Comment: I thank both of you for your precious contributions

Answer (score 1):

founds=establishes.  So television's "peculiar sense of presentness" establishes its claim to immediacy.

However, this is nearly a tautology, because "presentness" is a near-synonym for immediacy. The sentence is babble and bloviation, puffery, piffle, balderdash.